# Horizontal flip when rotation is set inline

Tags: jquery, css, rotation

I'm trying to do a horizontal flip of an image with css/jquery, but can't figure out to flip horizontally when a rotation of the image has been made.

**css:**

```
.horizontal-flip {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

**html:**

```
<img class="product-img horizontal-flip" src="/x.jpg" alt="products name">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".outfits").on('click', '.outfit .rotate-horizontal', function() {                  
    $(".product-img").toggleClass("horizontal-flip");
});
```

**Above works fine.**

When I do a rotation of the image, like

```
$(".product-img").rotate(90); //with jQuery rotate-plugin
```

then the html of the image looks like: *(in Firebug)*

```
<img class="product-img horizontal-flip" src="/x.jpg" alt="products name" style="transform: rotate(90deg);">
```

***but then the inline-style transform: rotate(90deg) is used and horizontal-flip seems to be ignored.***

I want the **rotated image (to 90deg) to be flipped**. What is the solution to that?

When it comes flipping vertically I solved the issue by rotating the image 180deg from current set angle of the image: (but when flipping horizontally it's not just about rotating)

**jQuery (and jQuery Rotate plugin)**

```
var img = $(".product-img");
var angle = img.getRotateAngle();
var newAngle = 180 - angle;
img.rotate(newAngle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a class as such,

```
img.flip-and-rotate{
    transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1);
}
```

or you could create your own js function achieving the same objective since I imagine you want to have a variable rotation. the problem here is that when you apply the rotation it clobbers the previous transform that is the mirror. (I am not accustomed to jquery and this is most likely not the best way to get it done, but it's just an example)

```
function rotate_and_flip(prop,x){
     $(prop).css('transform', 'rotate('+ x +'deg) scaleX(-1)');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know HOWTO go on with it :-) I tried to a separate rotate and separate flip, and of course that won't work because transform-property is used in both cases.